# Pyspark: Random forest featureSubsetStrategy not accepting int or float

Tags: python, pyspark, random-forest

I'm building a random forest classifier using pyspark. I want to set `featureSubsetStrategy` to be a number rather than `auto`, `sqrt`, etc. The documentation states:

```
featureSubsetStrategy = Param(parent='undefined', name='featureSubsetStrategy', doc='The number of features to consider for splits at each tree node. Supported options: auto, all, onethird, sqrt, log2, (0.0-1.0], [1-n].')
```

However, when for example I choose a number such as `0.2`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid param value given for param "featureSubsetStrategy". Could not convert <class 'float'> to string type
```

The same happens if I was to use `featureSubsetStrategy=5`. How do you set it so it can be a int or float?

Example:

```
# setting target label
label_col = 'veh_pref_Economy'

# random forest parameters
max_depth = 2
subset_strategy = 0.2037
impurity = 'gini'
min_instances_per_node = 41
num_trees = 1
seed = 1246

rf_econ_gen = (RandomForestClassifier()
                 .setLabelCol(label_col)
                 .setFeaturesCol("features")
                 .setMaxDepth(max_depth)
                 .setFeatureSubsetStrategy(subset_strategy)
                 .setImpurity(impurity)
                 .setMinInstancesPerNode(min_instances_per_node)
                 .setNumTrees(num_trees)
                 .setSeed(seed))
```

This returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py in _set(self, **kwargs)
    418                 try:
--> 419                     value = p.typeConverter(value)
    420                 except TypeError as e:

~/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py in toString(value)
    203         else:
--> 204             raise TypeError("Could not convert %s to string type" % type(value))
    205 

TypeError: Could not convert <class 'float'> to string type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-71b9c2a0f1a0> in <module>()
      3                  .setFeaturesCol("features")
      4                  .setMaxDepth(max_depth)
----> 5                  .setFeatureSubsetStrategy(subset_strategy)
      6                  .setImpurity(impurity)
      7                  .setMinInstancesPerNode(min_instances_per_node)

~/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/regression.py in setFeatureSubsetStrategy(self, value)
    632         Sets the value of :py:attr:`featureSubsetStrategy`.
    633         """
--> 634         return self._set(featureSubsetStrategy=value)
    635 
    636     @since("1.4.0")

~/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py in _set(self, **kwargs)
    419                     value = p.typeConverter(value)
    420                 except TypeError as e:
--> 421                     raise TypeError('Invalid param value given for param "%s". %s' % (p.name, e))
    422             self._paramMap[p] = value
    423         return self

TypeError: Invalid param value given for param "featureSubsetStrategy". Could not convert <class 'float'> to string type
```

Comment: Passing in a string works: `subset_strategy = "0.2037"`, seems like it could be bad documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I tried passing it as a string myself and didn't get an error but it didn't seem right and wasn't sure what was happening under the hood. It's a classic spark problem.

Comment: The pyspark implementation is just a wrapper on the Java version. The [Java docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/RandomForest.html) indicate that `featureSubsetStrategy` is a `String`.

Comment: @pault:  Thanks, one more question. it says it can also take a value of `[1-n]`, does this mean if there are 50 features and I want to use 10 of them for each  tree, do I enter `9` or `10`. Or have I completely misinterpreted how it works?

Comment: My interpretation is that you'd have to enter `10` for `10 features`. You'd have to select at least one feature at each tree, which is why the lower bound is `1`. You could test by building a Forest with 1 tree and seeing how many features were picked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place it as string.

```
subset_strategy = "0.2037"

rf_econ_gen = (RandomForestClassifier()
                 .setFeatureSubsetStrategy(subset_strategy))
```